# Why refreshing my mq patch leaves modified files in the working directory?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

Please, observe:

```
PS Z:\dev> hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
PS Z:\dev> hg st
A windows\NC\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\StartTask.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\Sample.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\StopTask.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\Task.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\Web\Sample.cs
PS Z:\dev> hg qrefresh -v
windows/Common/Shunra.Common.Contract/Shunra.Common.Contract.SL.csproj
windows/NC/NC.Client.SL.Web/Bootstrapper.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent.Contract/NC.Entities.Agent.Contract.csproj
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/AgentInfo.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/Sample.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/StopTask.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/Task.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/NC.Entities.Agent.csproj
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/AgentInfo.DTO.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/AgentInfo.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/Sample.DTO.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/Sample.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/SampleSet.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/StartTask.DTO.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/StartTask.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/StopTask.DTO.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Agent/Web/StopTask.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/AgentPortal.AgentEntitiesMarshal.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/AgentPortal.PrimitivesMarshal.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/AgentPortal.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/ExecutionInfoProvider.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/Handlers/AgentInfoHandler.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/Handlers/SampleHandler.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/Handlers/TaskHandler.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/IExecutionInfoProvider.PrimitivesMarshal.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/IProtocolMetadataResolver.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/IProtocolValuesHelper.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/Mobile/Web/MobileRunReport.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/NC.Entities.Server.csproj
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/ProtocolMetadataResolver.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities.Server/ProtocolValuesHelper.cs
windows/NC/NC.Entities/Rest/ProtoBufSerializer.cs
windows/NC/NC.ProtoBuf/NC.ProtoBuf.SL.csproj
windows/nc/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/PrimitiveCollection.cs
windows/nc/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/StartTask.cs
windows/nc/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/String2String.cs
windows/nc/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/StringTPair.cs
windows/nc/NC.Entities.Agent/DTO/StringTPairList.cs
PS Z:\dev> hg st
A windows\NC\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\StartTask.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\Sample.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\StopTask.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\DTO\Task.cs
A windows\nc\NC.Entities.Agent\Web\Sample.cs
PS Z:\dev>
```

What is unclear to me is why **hg status** returns the same added files after I have refreshed the MQ patch? Note, that these files do appear in the verbose output of **hg qrefresh.**

What am I supposed to do with it now?

Thanks.

Comment: @Idan - please rearrange your reply as an answer, because you are correct!

Comment: @Idan - please provide a formal answer, so that you can be credited for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casing of `nc` and `NC` directories in the files that were left out is different between `hg qrefresh -v` output and `hg st`.

Try forgetting the files reported by `hg st` and add them with the proper casing.

Comment: I did that and more - I have qpoped the patches and then just editted the patch files to fix the case. Apparently Mercurial core treats case differences correctly (on Windows), but not the MQ extension.